# how to get the value of a radio button on jsp

Tags: javascript, radio-button

I'm trying to get the value of a radio button on my JSP page with

```
document.getElementById('rButton').value
```

when I press a submit type button, but the line above only returns the value the radio button started with. It does not return the actual value of it. (true/false)

How can I check the actual value of the radio Button?

I'd appreciate some help. :)

Thanks.

Comment: Is it of any relevance that the page is generated with JSP, don't you ask only about the JavaScript?

Comment: well, I usually do not work on webpages so I have no idea. I goes not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Radio buttons](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/Input) (and checkboxes) have a [`checked` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLInputElement). Their `value` property/attribute is the value that is sent when they are checked.

Answer (score 0):

try `checked` instead of `value`.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<input type="radio" name="group2" value="Water"> Water<br>
<input type="radio" name="group2" value="Beer" checked> Beer<br>
<input type="radio" name="group2" value="Wine"> Wine ​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Javascript:

```
var radioBtns=document.getElementsByName("group2");
for(i=0;i<radioBtns.length; i++){
    if(radioBtns[i].checked){
        alert(radioBtns[i].value);
    }
}​​
```